# Ошибка в Ruby on Rails при создании модели

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Пытаюсь создать модель:

```
rails g model Post title:string body:text
```

Но появляется ошибка:

```
    /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionview-6.0.0.rc1/lib/action_view/cache_expiry.rb:30:in `clear_cache_if_necessary': undefined method `execute_if_updated' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionview-6.0.0.rc1/lib/action_view/cache_expiry.rb:11:in `before'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:607:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `catch'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block in default_terminator'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block in halting'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in invoke_before'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `each'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `invoke_before'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:111:in `run!'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:73:in `block in run!'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `tap'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `run!'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:86:in `wrap'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-6.0.0.rc1/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:51:in `reload!'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:168:in `serve'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:145:in `block in run'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `loop'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application.rb:139:in `run'
    from /home/alexandr/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/alexandr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /home/alexandr/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

Что я не так делаю?

Answer (score 0):

Это задокументированное [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/36093) в Rails 6.0.0.rc1. Оно уже исправлено, фикс попадёт в следующую версию. Решения два - дождаться появления следующей версии или вернуться к рельсам 5.2